# Is such a function integrable?

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued $2\pi$ periodic function on $\mathbb R$, integrable on compact intervals. Let $f$ be differentiable at $x_0$.  We define
$$
g(x)=\frac{f(x_0+x)-f(x_0-x)}{2 \sin x} 
$$
for $x\in (0,\pi)$.

This $g$ has  the limit $g(0^+)=f'(x_0)$ because
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{f(x_0+x)-f(x)}{x}+\frac{f(x_0-x)-f(x)}{-x}\right)\frac{x}{\sin x}
$$
I don't know about the limit $g(\pi^-)$.
Is $g$ integrable on $(0,\pi)$?

Comment: In your hypothesis, f is not supposed to be differentiable

Comment: I forget. $f$ should be differentiable at $x_0$. I just have edited.

Comment: Then we would like to have f differentiable at $x_0 + \pi$ too. Suppose you have a jump at $x_0+\pi$, it may not be integrable

Comment: But since $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic,  $f(x_0+\pi)=f(x_0-\pi)$.

Comment: Yes, that's not the problem. Suppose that $$f(x) = 1 \text{ if } x\in [x_0-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi, x_0+\pi+2k\pi[, 0 \text{ elsewhere}$$. Then g is not integrable

Comment: Many thanks for  help.